# Unset spawn point on protected servers?

Tags: terraria

While playing on some protected server, I noticed that once I had set my spawn point to one of the beds on the map, I could not revert to the default spawn point, since the bed as well as the room was protected from griefing.

Is there any other way to revert to the default spawn point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sleep in a bed outside the protected area then that will be your spawn point. Then destroying that bed will set your spawn back to default. This *may* set your spawn back to the first bed, but I doubt it.

Comment: You seem to think that this question is about Minecraft, but funnily enough, this solution is correct anyway. :)

Comment: Also: in both games, destroying your home bed, then placing it back in the same spot, won't reset your spawn point.

Comment: @lunboks I didn't, I just got confused towards then end.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's worse though.