# Protecting objects in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I run a dedicated server for Terraria and have a bit of a problem lately with younger people (such as my brother or a friend's brother) playing and finding it hilarious to:

1. Cheat and give themselves stacks of 999 Dynamite.
2. Throw the dynamite into tunnels/houses/networks of both that take me >12 hours to make.
3. Throw the dynamite into the ocean/caves etc which ruins the exploration value of the map.

This can at times be infuriating.

I've come across vague references to protecting stuff in Terraria - is this possible?

If so, is it something that I do through the server software or the game itself?

Edit:
Here is one such reference to 'protected' tiles: [Unset spawn point on protected servers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33902/unset-spawn-point-on-protected-servers)

Comment: Is banning the griefers not an option?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Depends, main issue is that I work full time and they don't, so when I get home everything has been destroyed already.

Comment: Also of course I could block that IP or whatever from joining but my friend that plays and his brothers use the same PC so it gets a little messy.

Comment: In that case, I suggest daily backups. Not sure how you could set something like that up, though.

Comment: The world automatically backs up **once** when it saves (which is every x minutes - not sure how frequent this is). Unfortunately the previous backup will get overwritten though so it's essentially useless in a scenario where the world has been demolished but I won't be home for greater than when the world next saves.

Comment: I posted the referenced question, and will expand on protected tiles in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it was I who wrote [the referenced question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33902/5581), I might as well shed some light on the topic here.

The protected servers I mentioned there are most likely *TShock* servers.
TShock is an alternative dedicated server for Terraria that adds in-game commands that enable, among other things, protection from griefing, spawning objects and enemies and  privilege groups.

At the time I write this TShock is not stable for Terraria 1.1 yet, but in case you're interested you could have a look at [TShock's website](http://tshock.co/xf/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

For an automatic backup, just write a simple batch script to copy world?.wld to another folder, then use Task Scheduler to run that once every day.

Edit: The world files are in `My Documents/My Games/Terraria/worlds`

Of course, this assumes you're using Windows. If not, I'm afraid I won't be as much help. Haven't been able to get Terraria running under Fedora :(